# Using TFS for drupal - Is that really a bad idea?

Tags: linux, tfs, xampp

We're considering TFS for our Drupal based projects and as a task management platform.

What the tuffest question over here is

> Does TFS (source control only) handles Drupal projects well as handling other .net related projects? (As it is Microsoft Product)

I admit that SVN does it job very well..

As it is a centralized decision I would like to know is it the best as SVN or any drawbacks there for using TFS in LINUX-XAMPP Environent ?

Comment: TFS is a heavy ALM system. It not only for VCS. If you just need version control and centralized, go for SVN.